# ¿Cómo hacer uso de eventos en botones para mostrar información al usuario con tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo dudas de como manejar los evento en los botones, tengo un botón en una interfaz que se llama (**ayuda**) mi duda es como muestro información de ayuda al usuario en el momento de dar **click** a dicho botón.

Lo que yo e implementado es hacer una función de nombre **info** 
y en dicha función imprimir un mensaje y después mandarlo a llamar desde mi botón,pero no me muestra nada.Si alguien sabe como hacer eso se lo agradecería mucho .

Según yo esta es la idea que pensé que funcionaria:

**Código**

```
def  info():
    print ("Paso1: De click en el botón de menú,posteriormente diríjase a.. ")
```

**En el botón de ayuda**

```
mnuAyuda.add_command(label="Acerca del Sistema",command=info)
```

Comment: ¿Quieres imprimirlo en consola o quieres mostrar un mensaje en tkinter?

Comment: Hola quiero mostrarlo en mi ventana de interfaz con tkinter ,pero  al momento de  que el usuario de click al botón (ayuda) le muestre la información.

Comment: Muy bien, muchas gracias por el dato Rafael Angel  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena opción es usar el  widget [`Text`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm). Permite mostrar texto en diferentes lineas y darle el formato deseado (fuente, subrayado, color, tabulaciones, etc)

Un ejemplo implementado un popup que se abre al pulsar el botón `Ayuda` seria el siguiente:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Ayuda_Dialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        text = ("Paso1: De click en el botón de menú, posteriormente diríjase a...\n" 
                "Paso2: ...\n"
                "Paso3: ...")

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.top.title("Ayuda")
        display = tk.Text(self.top)
        display.pack()
        display.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
        display.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        b = tk.Button(self.top, text="Cerrar", command=self.cerrar)
        b.pack(pady=5)

    def cerrar(self):
        self.top.destroy()


class Main_Window:
    def __init__(self,  root):
        root.geometry("200x100")
        tk.Button(root, text="Ayuda!",  command = self.ayuda).pack()
    def ayuda(self):
        Ayuda_Dialog(root)


if __name__ == "__main__":            
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main_Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Igual que se implementa en una ventana secundaria se puede implementar en la ventana principal.

> **Nota:** Código para Python 3.x, para Python 2.x cambiar el import por `import Tkinter as tk`.

**Ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Edicion:**

Si en vez de un botón queremos usar un Menu para lanzarlo, el procedimiento es el mismo:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Ayuda_Dialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        text = ("Paso1: De click en el botón de menú, posteriormente diríjase a...\n" 
                "Paso2: ...\n"
                "Paso3: ...")

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.top.title("Ayuda")
        display = tk.Text(self.top)
        display.pack()
        display.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
        display.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        b = tk.Button(self.top, text="Cerrar", command=self.cerrar)
        b.pack(pady=5)

    def cerrar(self):
        self.top.destroy()


class Main_Window:
    def __init__(self,  root):
        root.geometry("200x100")
        mnuAyuda = tk.Menu(root)
        mnuAyuda.add_command(label="Ayuda", command=self.ayuda)
        root.config(menu=mnuAyuda)

    def ayuda(self):
        Ayuda_Dialog(root)


if __name__ == "__main__":            
    root = tk.Tk()
    Main_Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias muy buena tu aportación ,solo tengo una ultima pregunta, funciona igual si yo hago uso de un  label en lugar de  Button ? ejemplo:  mnuAyuda.add_command(label="Ayuda")

Comment: @Airam con lo de "label" supongo que te refieres al item de un [Menu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm) por la sintaxis. Si ,es igual, seria `mnuAyuda.add_command(label="Ayuda"), command=self.ayuda)`. he editado la pregunta agregando un ejemplo simple.